# How to send and receive data from one xib window to another in Mac OS application using swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am creating a Mac OS application and I need to sent a json object from one xib window to another. i am trying like follows :

```
if let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:AnyObject]{
    if(responseJSON.count == 2){
        //Run in Main Thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            let dashboard = Dashboard()
            dashboard.showWindow(responseJSON)  //This is my another xib
            self.window?.close()
        }
```

I don't know how to receive this in that window and use , can anyone help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to `Dashboard`'s `init` method. Have it store the response in an instance variable. Then, later on when `Dashboard` loads its UI, have it read the instance variable and set the UI up appropriately.

Comment: Can you tell how to specify it inside the ` init() ` I mean I also have to specify it with a data type so can you suggest me ?

Comment: Expose a member from Dashboard and set that member here like dashboard.data = responseJSON

In Dashboard class, load the same filled data i.e., self.data in windowDidLoad function.